# vote to reopen question

Tags: discussion

per the comments, a table structure was asked for to make the question more clear

[Understanding the distance relationships in a Longitude and Latitude equation from an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613138/please-help-understand-the-distance-relationships-in-a-longitude-and-latitude-eq)

I added the table structure.

In this question I have 5 variables. I know three, and I am trying to understand what the relation one has to the other 2.  Given I know :minlat, :minlong, and :distance, what I am trying to figure out is how they affect :maxlat and :maxlong.

How is this not a real question?

Answer (score 5):

> How is this not a real question?

Because it's unanswerable in its current form. You said that the PHP program takes some input, and inside of code that you can't access generates the values that you're confused about. If you don't have access to the code - and therefore can't post it for us to see - how are *we* supposed to know what it does?

Comment: Obviously key points were missed. I said that I could not edit the code, but that I COULD edit the 5 variables that the code produced. If I know the min lat and long and distance, then I should be able to derive max lat and long. this is what the question is trying to figure out.

Comment: @user658182 At which point I'd say it stops being a programming question at all, and should have been closed as off-topic.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I think it's become "can you explain to me how this SQL code works" which is a legitimate question, though at the moment it qualifies for psychic answering because it's not asking that precisely

Comment: you have a geolocation TAG!! you do realize calculations are part of programming right? If not SO.com, then where should this question be asked? Do you think the people at math.se will analyze this question and the sql query?

Comment: @KateGregory The SQL query seemed pretty irrelevant, personally, but I can't say I made much effort to read all of it (the lack of code formatting doesn't help). It's just using the values of the variables, though, so didn't strike me as useful in answering *how* those values are calculated.

Comment: @user658182 The existence of a tag doesn't necessarily mean the question is on-topic, though. Answerable questions about specific programming problems that relate to geolocation are on-topic, questions about non-programming aspects of geolocation aren't.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist the OP wants to know what they represent. Seeing how they're used can answer that. At the moment, the best bet is the related questions list since no-one can answer the question while it's closed.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist so, you are simply in the business of going through and marking things to be closed you don't fully read? give much attention to? don't understand? Really, that seems fair.. How about some constructive feedback about how to clarify the question. To me it's clear, but if Kate and others think it's kinda vague, then I am happy to alter the title, etc, to be clearer with a little direction. I already have mentioned my intention in better understanding the relationships among these variables.  The SQL statement was for a programmer who hopefully had seen it before and can clarify.

Comment: @user658182: your tone is inappropriate and unconstructive, especially given that Anthony Grist didn't vote to close your question himself.

Comment: @KateGregory I was under the impression that the question was "Given `:minlon` and `:distance`, how is the value of `:maxlon` calculated?" That seems (though correct me if I'm wrong) to be different to what you think is being asked.